# Polymorphic Associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

How do polymorphic associations work in Rails?  What are their advantages?  Is there a way to add `belongs_to` method just by running a migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ryan has a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) about this that is pretty good.

Belongs_to isn't something you add to a migration, you add it to the model.  In the migration, you have to add the foreign key column.  For example if you have a post model that belongs to a user, you'd add the user_id column to the post activerecord in a migration.  Then you add

```
 belongs_to :user
```

in the post model separately.  Then rails will do its magic in the background to give you the proxy collections in the user model.