# Simplest way to store two has_many relationships with one model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many-through, model-associations

A `'user` has many `posts` and a `product` has many `posts`, and any given `post` can belong to either a `user` or a `product` but not both.

I think a `has_many :through` relationship stored in a `posts_relationships` table and written like:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, :through => posts_relationships
```

and

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts, :through => posts_relationships
```

would express what I need.  *Is that the correct and simplest way to do it?*  It's not a complex relationship so I want to write it as simply as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider polymorphic association.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :as=>:postings
end

Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :as=>:postings
end

class Post
  belongs_to :posting, :polymorphic=> :true
end
```

Comment: That sounds like what I need. I just watched the screencast in the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697840/polymorphic-associations-in-rails) question but it's quite old. I'll look around for Rails 3-specific tutorials on polymorphic associations.

Comment: The screencast isn't much different (if at all) from the implementation, it just can be hard to wrap around thinking about them in an object context. Really it's just a foreign key relationship, once you start thinking that way you start to realize that the implementation isn't that different. Here are the [Polymorphic Association Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Polymorphic+Associations)